# Analyticity of The function defined by integral

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

In page 28 of the book 'Poisson Processes' written by Kingman,

there exists the function
$$\exp{\int \exp{(zf(x))}-1 \,m(dx)} $$

where

$z$ is complex which the integral converges, 
$f(x)$ is a measurable function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ 
such that $\int \min{\{|f(x)|,1\}} \, m(dx)$ is finite, 
and $m$ is a measure which finite on compact sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Is this function is analytic on convergence region of the integral ?

that is

1. Is the convergence region of the integral open connected?
2. If 1 is true, then is the function $\exp{\int \exp{(zf(x))}-1 \,m(dx)} $ analytic?

Actually, I am trying to understand the campbell theorem in the book. but the proof in the book have some jumps of logic..

Comment: "the proof in the book have some jumps of logic." No it has not.

Comment: To Did. The book just say about analyticity and analytic continuation , do not show that

Comment: In my world, "jumps of logic" has a precise meaning. What you seem to be complaining about is that you are lacking some prerequisites necessary to follow some reasonings in the book. This is entirely different. As a matter of fact, my advice would be to stop entirely using the words "gaps", "jumps of logic" and the like in such contexts, except when there is very good reasons to think they are appropriate. (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: @Did In my world, Meaning of'jumps of logic' is not same as yours. Please see the context. But if you feels like that, I appologize. My mother tongue is not english. I want you to understand this.